# How to typesafe an object one of the properties of which might be of different name?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I want to type an object where I don't know the name of one of properties, but know the type of its value. So it's something like that:

```
type PagedResponse<T> = {
  Suppliers: Array<T>; // <- this prop might have different name
  nextPageToken: number;
  total: number;
};
```

`Suppliers` prop might be of different name - `Products` or anything else, but it should be of type `Array<T>`. How do I type something like that? Is it possible to pass the name of that last prop as another argument to the type.

Comment: I doubt this is possible in a clean manner since the type information will be removed after the compilation stage. What you could do though would be `type PagedResponse<T> = { [key: string]: Array<T>; nextPageToken: number; total: number }`, but I think that's definitely not what you are looking for

Comment: I don't care about after compilation stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
type PagedResponse<T, K extends string = string> = {
  nextPageToken: number;
  total: number;
} & {
    [P in K]: Array<T>;
}

const response: PagedResponse<number, 'Products'> = {
    Products: [1, 2, 3],
    total: 10,
    nextPageToken: 20
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
type PagedResponse<T> = {
 [prop: string]: Array<T>; // <- this prop might have different name
 nextPageToken: number;
 total: number;
};
```